# Running scripts independently on Raspberry Pi

Tags: linux, ssh, debian, terminal, python

I have a couple of python programs, such as one which checks if the Collatz Conjecture is applicable for a given number or not, and writes output to a file (it runs on a Raspberry Pi).

Although I know that it hasn't been disproved for up to like a quadrillion or something, I just want to run it for programming practice. Although I can set it to start up when the RPi boots, and start it through a ssh session, the main reason I’m using a Pi is so that it can go upto numbers like 1 billion, while not consuming much power even if performance isn’t practical.

When I start it through an SSH Session by typing `python col.py`, it stops running if I terminate the session. How can I start the script using SSH so that it doesn't stop when I terminate the session (continues till it ends or RPi shuts down)?

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/41959/how-to-send-jobs-to-background-without-stopping-them related.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There’s a few ways to do this actually .

The first question I’d ask myself is ”Do I need to see/interact with this task later?”

If yes, I’d use [screen](http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/) or [tmux](http://tmux.sourceforge.net/)—This is an example of it with `htop`—<kbd>ctrl</kbd> <kbd>a</kbd>-<kbd>d</kbd> detaches a screen session and `screen -r` reattaches it. A detached screen session works even after you have closed the terminal but I was too lazy to do that here.

[image]

Else I’d use `nohup python col.py &` to just run the task in the background.

Comment: I'm going to use nohup as it'll let me redirect terminal output to a file and works great after session is terminated. ty

Comment: ... oops. Yeah, needed the & there didn't I? I was *significantly* more focused on using screen ;p

Answer (score 5):

Using [`screen`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/screen) is fine, but [`nohup`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/nohup) with [`&`](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-command-line-run-in-background/) should work as well.

So in your case just run the command like this:

```
nohup python col.py &
```

Just so you understand how each item works:

- `nohup`: That stands for “no hangup” which means that even if your terminal session is disconnected, the process that is connected to that `nohup` command will keep on runnig.
- `&`: That ampersand in this context tells the shell to run the command that precedes it as a background process.

If you were to just run this:

```
nohup python col.py
```

The `python col.py` would run, but not as a background process; it would be a foreground process locking you into the terminal.  And if you ran this:

```
python col.py &
```

The `python col.py` would run in the background, but the second you log out the `python col.py` command would terminate.

Doing the `nohup` and `&` combo is the simplest, most commonly used method of running unattended tasks as an independent background process.